# Will using a compressed filesystem over an encrypted volume improve performance?

Tags: filesystems, encryption, compression, btrfs, dm-crypt

Encryption/decryption is often the main bottleneck when accessing an encrypted volume. Would using a filesystem with a fast transparent compression  (such as BTRFS + LZO) help? The idea is that there would be less data to encrypt, and if the compression is significantly faster than the encryption algorithm, the overall processing time would be less.

**Update:** As Mat pointed out, it depends on the compressibility of the actual data. Of course, I assume that its compressible, like source code or documents. Of course it has no meaning using it for media files (but I guess it won't hurt too much, as [BTRFS tries to detect incompressible files](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Compression#What_happens_to_incompressible_files.3F).)

Since testing this idea is a very time consuming process, I'm asking if somebody has already some experience with this. I tested just a very simple setup, and it seems to show a difference:

```
$ touch BIG_EMPTY
$ chattr +c BIG_EMPTY
$ sync ; time ( dd if=/dev/zero of=BIG_EMPTY bs=$(( 1024*1024 )) count=1024 ; sync )
...
real    0m26.748s
user    0m0.008s
sys 0m2.632s

$ touch BIG_EMPTY-n
$ sync ; time ( dd if=/dev/zero of=BIG_EMPTY-n bs=$(( 1024*1024 )) count=1024 ; sync )
...
real    1m31.882s
user    0m0.004s
sys 0m2.916s
```

Comment: If you downvote, I'd appreciate a comment why. I'm trying to improve performance of an encrypted disk, and this seems to me a valid question. If it isn't, please explain why.

Comment: @Petr: this isn't really answerable if you think about it. If you're storing highly-compressible stuff in there, then yes that might work (you'd have to test it though). If you're storing non-compressible stuff (archives, media in compressed containers, ...), it might very well make it much worse.

Comment: @Mat, you're right, I assume of course that the stored data is compresssible - like documents or source code.

Comment: Using all zeros in a compression test is absurdly optimistic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I did a small benchmark. It only tests writes though.

Test data is a Linux kernel source tree (linux-3.8), already unpacked into memory (/dev/shm/ tmpfs), so there should be as little influence as possible from the data source. I used compressible data for this test since compression with non-compressible files is nonsense regardless of encryption.

Using btrfs filesystem on a 4GiB LVM volume, on LUKS [aes, xts-plain, sha256], on RAID-5 over 3 disks with 64kb chunksize. CPU is a Intel E8400 2x3Ghz without AES-NI. Kernel is 3.8.2 x86_64.

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash

PARTITION="/dev/lvm/btrfs"
MOUNTPOINT="/mnt/btrfs"

umount "$MOUNTPOINT" >& /dev/null

for method in no lzo zlib
do
    for iter in {1..3}
    do
        echo Prepare compress="$method", iter "$iter"
        mkfs.btrfs "$PARTITION" >& /dev/null
        mount -o compress="$method",compress-force="$method" "$PARTITION" "$MOUNTPOINT"
        sync
        time (cp -a /dev/shm/linux-3.8 "$MOUNTPOINT"/linux-3.8 ; umount "$MOUNTPOINT")
        echo Done compress="$method", iter "$iter"
    done
done
```

So in each iteration, it makes a fresh filesystem, and measures the time it takes to copy the linux kernel source from memory and umount. So it's a pure write-test, zero reads.

The results:

```
Prepare compress=no, iter 1

real 0m12.790s
user 0m0.127s
sys 0m2.033s
Done compress=no, iter 1
Prepare compress=no, iter 2

real 0m15.314s
user 0m0.132s
sys 0m2.027s
Done compress=no, iter 2
Prepare compress=no, iter 3

real 0m14.764s
user 0m0.130s
sys 0m2.039s
Done compress=no, iter 3
Prepare compress=lzo, iter 1

real 0m11.611s
user 0m0.146s
sys 0m1.890s
Done compress=lzo, iter 1
Prepare compress=lzo, iter 2

real 0m11.764s
user 0m0.127s
sys 0m1.928s
Done compress=lzo, iter 2
Prepare compress=lzo, iter 3

real 0m12.065s
user 0m0.132s
sys 0m1.897s
Done compress=lzo, iter 3
Prepare compress=zlib, iter 1

real 0m16.492s
user 0m0.116s
sys 0m1.886s
Done compress=zlib, iter 1
Prepare compress=zlib, iter 2

real 0m16.937s
user 0m0.144s
sys 0m1.871s
Done compress=zlib, iter 2
Prepare compress=zlib, iter 3

real 0m15.954s
user 0m0.124s
sys 0m1.889s
Done compress=zlib, iter 3
```

With `zlib` it's a lot slower, with `lzo` a bit faster, and in general, not worth the bother (difference is too small for my taste, considering I used easy-to-compress data for this test).

I'd make a read test also but it's more complicated as you have to deal with caching.

Comment: Great test. Considering that in many cases data are compressible (like `/usr`), it would be helpful. I suppose a read test could be done the same way by simply [clearing cache](http://serverfault.com/q/107840/135336).

Comment: I tested reading using a similar script, trying to avoid cache, and it seems that no compression is better than lzo. Probably the time consumed by compression is higher than what it saves on the encryption side.

Comment: For read speeds, I get best results for zlib (42-46s), followed by lzo (46-48s), followed by no compression (58-59s). My read test was `time (xargs cat < /dev/shm/files | md5sum)` (files being all files in the linux-3.8 kernel tree), after `sync ; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` and a freshly mounted fs, as the write bench umounts. So... zlib takes longer to write but is fastest to read. Provided your files are all easy to compress. I still won't bother with it personally, but ymmv.